# How to set timeout feature for FileSystemWatcher?

Tags: c#, file, filesystemwatcher

Apologies if this question is too simple, I am new to the subject.

I am creating a few files, and need to wait until they are completed OR until some period of time has elapsed (this is what I call the timeout).

`FileSystemWatcher` is perfect for "wait until they are completed", but I cannot see a parameter that would govern its life span.

Using `Tread.Sleep` seems to defeat the purpose (?) - if its usage were correct, `FileSystemWatcher` would not exist, we would just `Tread.Sleep while !File.Exists`.

So, what is the easiest right way to implement it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[FileSystemWatcher.WaitForChanged Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3tf46w9.aspx)

MSDN syas

`A synchronous method that returns a structure that contains specific information on the change that occurred, given the type of change you want to monitor and the time (in milliseconds) to wait before timing out.`